# Can mind be free from becoming?

Tags: mind, becoming

Can mind be free from becoming  (Suffering) ?
I should be and I should that.
I am thin and I want to be a body builder. 
I am this and I want to that.
Can mind free from becoming?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! If you want to be free of something, get rid of the cause of it. The cause of becoming is attachment. The cause of attachment is craving. Work on getting rid of the craving to end all suffering.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For more information please see [an3.66](https://suttacentral.net/an3.66/en/sujato)

*They understand:
‘Formerly there was greed, which was unskillful. Now there is none, so that’s skillful.
Formerly there was hate, which was unskillful. Now there is none, so that’s skillful.
Formerly there was delusion, which was unskillful. Now there is none, so that’s skillful.’
So they live without wishes in the present life, extinguished, cooled, experiencing bliss, having become holy in themselves.”*

Answer (score 1):

I will attack this question from another points of view. There is a real paradox in the idea of the end of becoming. In the process of end of becoming, we are becoming more Buddhist or more serene.

This leads the natural question: Is Buddhism seeing the true ontology or is it making one see a Buddhist ontology?

This topic is rather dense and requires a lot of framework, so I will tell you, from faith, that the 3rd noble truth says there is an end to suffering and thus and end to bhavana (becoming).

If you want to read more, refer to ["The Paradox of Becoming"](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/paradoxofbecoming.pdf) by Thanissaro Bhikku. It is a beautiful read and leads to many insights, if one spends time with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no since it seems to me Mind is what we need to be free of becoming.

Answer (score 0):

Becoming exists when desire exists. Desire for the abandonment of desire is the last desire and there is no more resolve on the synthesis of created phenomena after that abandonment.